# I want to have 2 different values in the same field of the same column in a mysql workbench table?

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench, workbench

Basically I need to create a table where one of the columns need to have 2 products within the same field. 
I have already created the rest of the table but when it comes to inputting more than one of the products into the same column it wont let me. I tried code it in many different ways but cannot seem to work out how to make it work if its possible, e.g "product1 and product2"  "product1,product2" etc..
Anyone know how this could be resolved? Much appreciated as I am new to workbench.

Comment: A database field can only have one value (per record); that value can be a list of values concatenated into a single string value, but that is almost always the wrong way to do things.

Comment: You cannot put a tuple into a column like that. Would concatenation work for your use case?

Comment: Yeah i wouldnt really want to concentrate it into a single value becuase that wouldnt make sense to the user. Its basically an integer for the ID, but because for one row there is two different ID's I want to put both of them in their for that order. Anyway i can do this?

Comment: If I for example put them into two separate rows then this would mean that theyre two seperate orders when they are not

Comment: Can you have like two rows for two products with same order id? That way you can retrieve all products placed under one particular order id.

Comment: So youre basically saying create the exact same values in two rows except change the product so that it is still classed as the same order. good idea. however can be abit long winded though if for example someone wanted 20 products then the table would be cluttered with loads of rows just for essentially 1 order. thank you @p raju

Answer (score 2):

If you find your data needs to have "a varying number of multiple values for one row", then (99 out of 100 times) the answer is another table to hold those values with reference to the "parent" row of the original table.

- The answer is NOT to duplicate the row except for varying it by that one field.
- The answer is almost never to concatenate the values together and cram them into the one field.
- The answer is sometimes (though rarely) to have multiple fields; with "empty" ones set to NULL. *But usually this is only when the multiple values have slightly separate meanings or purposes, or their order matters.*

Answer (score -1):

You can store multiple values in a comma separated fashion (A,B) or as a JSONArray ([A,B]) in MySQL if the need arises. But you won't be able to perform any operations using them, as MySQL will consider the set as a single entity.

What you are looking for is one of the reasons people use PostgreSQL. It supports arrays of data types that can be filled in a cell. i.e. along with Integer it also has Integer[] datatype and text[] likewise. It also has support for array related operations and you can handle them well.

One thing to remember is that a normalised database structure won't need this. You can break down your problem to solve it with simple SQL as follows:
Table:

1->Fruits->Apples,Mangoes
2->Colors->Red,Green,Blue

Can be stored as
Table1:
1->Fruits
2->Colors

Table2:
1->Apples
1->Mangoes
2->Red
2->Green
2->Blue

Comment: Whats so bad about this answer?